# OpenCV "not a member of 'cv'" errors while trying to compile some code

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to compile the following visual odometry library: https://github.com/HKUST-Aerial-Robotics/VINS-Mono but in attempting to do so with OpenCV 4.0, I'm getting several "error: 'x' is not a member of 'cv' errors. There were several of these involving things like RGB2GRAY that I was able to Google and figure out how to update, but there's a couple errors remaining that I haven't been able to figure out how to update. These are as follows:

1. error: 'SHAPE_CROSS' is not a member of 'cv'
2. error: 'SHAPE_RECT' is not a member of 'cv'
3. error: 'TERMCRIT_EPS' is not a member of 'cv'
4. error: 'TERMCRIT_ITER' is not a member of 'cv'

Would anyone know what the fixes for these would be for OpenCV 4.0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont find out any "SHAPE_CROSS" in that repository

Comment: Hi @Dominota! I'm finding all these in the Chessboard.cc file, under camera_model/src/chessboard/Chessboard.cc, for example, in line 215 there's a SHAPE_CROSS which I modified to be cv::SHAPE_CROSS (similar to how I fixed the RGB2GRAY errors), but that fix doesn't work here

Comment: LOL, you show only "SHAPE_CROSS why it is "CV_SHAPE_CROSS". That's why i did not find exactly that work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found my solution after some more Googling:

`CV_SHAPE_CROSS` --> `cv::MORPH_CROSS`

`CV_SHAPE_RECT` --> `cv::MORPH_RECT`

`CV_TERMCRIT_EPS` --> `cv::TermCriteria::EPS`

`CV_TERMCRIT_ITER` --> `cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER`